# recursion, global variables, and OpenMP

Tags: c, recursion, parallel-processing

I'm having troubles with a function that calls itself
the proper way of threading with openmp is unclear to me on that case.

```
long *arrayofindex; 
int length, N;

void gen(long index)
{
    if(index == 0)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int a=0; a<N; ++a)
        {
            #pragma omp critical
            {
            gen(index+1);
            ++arrayofindex[index];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(arrayofindex[index]=0; arrayofindex[index]<N; ++arrayofindex[index])
        {
            if(index < length-1)
                gen(index+1);
            else printf("%ld\n", arrayofindex[index]);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    length = 5, N = 4;
    arrayofindex = (long*) malloc(length * sizeof(long));
    for(int i=0; i<length; ++i)
        arrayofindex[index] = 0;
    gen(0);
}
```

the way I did it, it runs several threads and is correct but doesn't seem to get any faster than without openmp support.

Is there an way through this ? or is it going to be helpless because of the way of the code.

The complete code https://github.com/e2002e/zhou

Comment: What is the initialization statement in `for(arrayofindex[index]; ...` supposed to accomplish for you?  Is that a typo?

Comment: Also, what does `criticalfunc()` do?  In particular, does it access the elements of `arrayofindex`?

Comment: Furthermore, `arrayofindex = (long*) malloc(5);` is almost surely wrong.  Did you mean `arrayofindex = malloc(5 * sizeof(long));`?

Comment: Ok, after noticing the use of `=` instead of `==` in `if(index = 0){`, I'm done.  As presented, this code has an infinite recursion.  Update the code to present a *bona fide* [mcve], or we are unlikely to be able to help you.

Comment: don't be so discouraging, I just did not copy and past this code hence the = instead of ==, i'm editiing it.
arrayofindex is initialized at all 0, and yes I forgot to multiply 5 by sizeof(long), thanks for your comments.

Comment: Your comment that "without taking into account what is going on in the 'criticalfunc' I miss hits on the function itself" seems to be saying that you have data dependencies between calls to `gen()` with different arguments. OpenMP has no magic solution for that.  But we can neither confirm nor suggest any mitigation without an MCVE to work with.  You have not yet presented one, for there is no definition of `criticalfunc()` (which indeed seems to be critical), nor any example input, expected output, or actual (erroneous) output.

Comment: I edited my question so that the issue might look clearer, yes I need a threaded access to arrayofindex

Comment: It isn't obvious to me what this is intended to do; can you explain?

Comment: this is just an iterator, N is the length of a word, and length is the length of the character set, this means total hit on the printf is length exponant N

Comment: In my complete code I use arrayofchar as an array to store the character set and use arrayofchar[arrayofindex[y]] inside a loopf for  y< N to generate a word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the code presented, the general objective is essentially to generate all the `N`-letter words that can be formed with a `length`-letter alphabet.  Each recursive call to `gen()` corresponds to one letter position, and so each time control reaches the bottom of the recursion, the first `N` elements of `arrayofindex` represent the letters of one word.

But it should be obvious that multiple threads running in parallel cannot use the same `arrayofindex`.  Each thread expects when it reaches the bottom of the recursion to find  in `arrayofindex` the values that *it* set along its recursive path.  That's fundamental to the approach.  If other threads are modifying `arrayofindex` at the same time then they all likely get mishmashes of values set by different threads.  Moreover, you probably don't get anything like the speedup you hope for, because the threads need to synchronize their accesses to `arrayofindex`.

---

**Note**: This problem has nothing in particular to do with recursion.  You would have exactly the same issue if you modified the code to be iterative instead of recursive -- which I, myself, would in fact do if I were looking to improve performance, though I do not demonstrate that here.

---

There are various ways to give each OMP thread its own working array.  If the space must continue to be dynamically allocated, then you should arrange for it to be allocated *inside* the parallel region, so that each thread allocates its own.  If you're willing and able to rely on variable-length arrays for this, however, then probably the only other thing you need is an OMP `private` clause attached to your `parallel for` construct.

For example, this variation on your code works for me:

```
void gen_tail(int length, int num_letters, int arrayofindex[], int position) {
    for (int letter = 0; letter < num_letters; letter++) {
        arrayofindex[position] = letter;
        if (position + 1 < length) {
            gen_tail(length, num_letters, arrayofindex, position + 1);
        } else {
            // this is the bottom ... do something with arrayofindex, such as:
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    putchar('A' + arrayofindex[i]);
                }
                putchar('\n');
            }
        }
    }
}

void gen(int length, int num_letters) {
    assert(length > 1);
    int arrayofindex[length];  // Note: VLA, _not_ dynamically allocated

    // Marking the array 'private' means each thread gets its own copy.
    // This would not have the needed effect if 'arrayofindex' were a pointer.
    #pragma omp parallel for private(arrayofindex)
    for (int letter = 0; letter < num_letters; letter++) {
        arrayofindex[0] = letter;
        gen_tail(length, num_letters, arrayofindex, 1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    gen(5, 4);
}
```

That emits the expected 1024 (== 4<sup>5</sup>) results for me, all distinct, as I have every reason to expect it should do.

Comment: works very well, BUT the threads, and overhead of implicit parallel for locks are slowing it I guess.

Comment: That would not be a surprise with my example code, @Yvain, given that it performs I/O in a critical region.  In fact, individual stream I/O calls for the same stream are synchronized automatically anyway; the critical region in the example is just to keep each thread's output together.  I anticipate that the I/O accounts for the lion's share of all work done by that code, and that will greatly limit the speedup available.  You should be able to do better by storing results in memory instead of on disk, or, possibly, having each thread write to a different file.

Comment: ok, another thing, I conserved the original fashing of the code and used a `#pragma omp taskloop on top of first iteration on the function, the one you kept for gen() in your example. There it does its job, I couldn't tell much without trying to pipe it to john-the-ripper which speed increases a little then, and I did not have to set a single other line than this one...

Comment: @Yvain an `omp taskloop` does not have different data-sharing implications than an `omp for`.  To the best of my understanding, however, an `omp taskloop` is useful only in the context of an enclosing `omp parallel` section.  Without one, I think you just have serial execution in a single thread, which explains why the data sharing does not cause a problem in that case.  Overall, I think you're I/O bound, not CPU bound, so parallelization is unlikely to help much.  Perhaps not at all.

Comment: that's exactly that, i saw my results with a difference that was due to the system.

Comment: also I removed the printf function and it runs faster with omp, at a scale expected by the number of cores since i rewrote this to generate with nested loop and use `omp parallel for collapse(n)`